# How to display trailing zeroes?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

How do I keep the trailing zeroes like the example below. When I input -.230 with no leading zeroes it only displays -0.23 without the trailing zero. But when I input -0.230 it yields the expected result which is -0.230.

```
Actual output: -.230 -> -0.23
Expected output: -.230 -> -0.230
```

I have also tried `String.Format("{0:0.000}", n)` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are converting to `string` so you can use the following

```
someNumber.ToString("N3");
```

See the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0) docs for details on how this works, about halfway down the page it also has examples of a bunch of different codes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are print the same number on which you have performed **string.format**.

Try to store the output of string.format and use that. I have used the same approach that you have used and got the expected answer. Refer following code

```
var n = -.23;
string str = string.Format("{0:0.000}", n);
Console.WriteLine(str); // This will give you an expected output

Console.WriteLine(n); // This won't give you an expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

`double` and `decimal` mentioned in the question, are quite *different* types. `double` is a binary *floating point* value and it doesn't keep trailing zeroes:

```
 double value = -0.230;

 Console.Write(value); // -0.23
```

Unlike `double`, `decimal` being [decimal floating-point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0) does store the trailing zeroes:

```
 decimal value = -0.230m; // note suffix "m" 

 Console.Write(value); // -0.230
```

When represented as `string` values of these types can be formatted, e.g. with `F3`
format string which stands for "3 digits after the decimal point":

```
  double v1  = -0.230;
  decimal v2 = -0.230m;

  Console.Write($"{v1:f3} {v2:f3}");
```

Outcome:

```
  -0.230 -0.230
```